# converting multiple text value in one column into different column

Tags: r, dataframe, nlp, tidyr

I have a large df file from a survey platform.  the columns contains one question(as a title) with all potential answer. I'm trying to separate each of this answer column into a new set of columns (with the name of answer as the the name of the new column).

after that i would like each new column to indicate if the value appears in the original column(with "1") to process the data more easily

```
     df<-data.frame("name"= c("John","mark","bell","elsa"),"what do you like to 
     eat"=c("apple","fries apple","peach","bread"))
```

original df

| name | What.do.you.like.to.eat |
| --- | --- |
| John | apple |
| Mark | fries apple |
| bell | peach |
| elsa | bread |

i'm using this code which works, but i'm sure there must be  more efficient/easier way of doing it, as i have a over 50 column like this.

```
    df<-df %>%
  separate(what.do.you.like.to.eat, c("apple","fries","peach","bread",NA ), remove = F)
df[,3:6]<-""
{
  df[,3] =  with(df, ifelse(grepl("apple", df$what.do.you.like.to.eat,ignore.case = T), 
                                             paste('1', df[,3]), 
                                             paste("", df[,3])))
  df[,4] =  with(df, ifelse(grepl("fries", df$what.do.you.like.to.eat,ignore.case = T), 
                            paste('1', df[,4]), 
                            paste("", df[,4])))
  df[,5] =  with(df, ifelse(grepl("peach", df$what.do.you.like.to.eat,ignore.case = T), 
                            paste('1', df[,5]), 
                            paste("", df[,5])))
  df[,6] =  with(df, ifelse(grepl("bread", df$what.do.you.like.to.eat,ignore.case = T), 
                            paste('1', df[,6]), 
                            paste("", df[,6])))
}
```

desire output

| name | What.do.you.like.to.eat | apple | fries | peach | bread |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | apple | 1 |  |  |  |
| Mark | fries apple | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| bell | peach |  |  | 1 |  |
| elsa | bread |  |  |  | 1 |

Comment: Honestly I'm struggling to understand it's kind of vague so could you provide a sample of your data and a sample of the expected result ?

Comment: just did, submitted by mistake with no example

Answer (score 1):

Ok i've done this tell me if this works for you :

```
my_df <- data.frame("name" = c("John","mark","bell","elsa"),
                "what do you like to eat" = c("apple","fries apple","peach","bread"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
my_var <- unique(sort(str_split(string = my_df$what.do.you.like.to.eat, pattern = " ", simplify = TRUE)))
my_pos <- which(my_var == "")
if (length(my_pos)) {
  my_var <- my_var[-my_pos]
}
my_col <- c(colnames(my_df), my_var)
my_miss <- setdiff(my_col, colnames(my_df))
my_df[my_miss] <- NA
my_f <- function(x, y) {
  my_var <- grep(pattern = colnames(my_df)[x], x = my_df[, y])
  if (length(my_var)) {
    my_df[my_var, x] <<- 1
  }
}
lapply(3:ncol(my_df), function(x) my_f(x, 2))
```

you can change this part to this :

```
my_df <- data.frame("name" = c("John","mark","bell","elsa"),
                "what do you like to eat" = c("i like apple","i love fries apple","i'm kind of peach","bread all the way"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
my_var <- unique(sort(str_split(string = 
my_df$what.do.you.like.to.eat, pattern = " ", simplify = TRUE)))
my_food <- c("apple", "fries", "bread", "peach")
my_var <- my_var[which(my_var %in% my_food)]
my_pos <- which(my_var == "")
if (length(my_pos)) {
  my_var <- my_var[-my_pos]
}
```

Comment: it's work great with this example, so thanks. the problem is that in the original df the answer are mainly  distinct string like "i like to eat apples";" i like bread very much"; etc. is there a way to define my_var so it could detect such string, or does it have to be added manually to this variable?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `purrr::map` to apply over your vector of answers and for each, check their presence in the string.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  name = c("John", "mark", "bell", "elsa"),
  "what do you like to eat" = c("apple", "fries apple", "peach", "bread")
)

ans <- c("apple", "fries", "peach", "bread")

map_dfc(ans,~ transmute(df, !!sym(.x) := str_detect(what.do.you.like.to.eat, .x))) %>%
  bind_cols(df, .)
#>   name what.do.you.like.to.eat apple fries peach bread
#> 1 John                   apple  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> 2 mark             fries apple  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#> 3 bell                   peach FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#> 4 elsa                   bread FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: thanks this works great, also with strings. is there an option to bind the outcome column with the bind_cols  function,  at specific location in the data frame.? (similar to : dplyr::relocate(ans, .after = name)